# angular-translate sanitisation fails with UTF characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sanitization, angular-translate

On Angular 1.3.x with latest version of angular-translate. Using `$sanitize` it seems there are problems when using filter or service directly, but it works when using the directive.

Suggestions?

Here is an example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngSanitize' ]);

myApp.config(function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy("sanitize");
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        UTF: 'öéü',
    });
});

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $translate) {
    $translate("UTF").then(function(trans) {
        $scope.UTFCTRL = trans;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate/master/angular-translate.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
        Wrong: <h1>{{ 'UTF' | translate }}</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        Ok: <h1 translate="UTF"></h1>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        Wrong: <h1>{{ UTFCTRL }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

On jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gnvpo6aa/

Comment: This is a WONTFIX for the translate filter at least: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/440 :´(
I'm having issues with both the filter and the service.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

At the moment, you have two options:

1. Use the strategy `sanitizeParameters` which will only sanitize the dynamic parameters, but not the actual translation (template). If you have the translation under control (but not the dynamic values), this will work.
2. Use the strategy `escape` (or `escapeParameters`) which does not use sanitization but escaping.

Disclaimer: I'm co-maintaining angular-translate.

Edit (12.01.2016): I'd created [this matrix overview of all variants](http://plnkr.co/edit/8BHONOjhsxBxxO9oVYOK?p=preview).

Comment: Found this via the issue 1011, thanks for the work around, and the plugin!

Comment: Having `sanitize` as strategy, UTF-8 characters seem to work when used with `translate="KEY"` attribute.

Comment: this because when using the translate directive the sanitize doesn't work... even html tags are acting as usual

Comment: @knalli : nice matrix, but it seems that the `null` strategy has the same effect as the 'sce' one

Comment: I guess you are mixing sanitizing and escaping. Using a sanitized strings does not result into escaped strings.

Comment: @knalli @LucasCimon Regarding Lucas' comment about strategies `null` and `sce` behaving the same in the matrix.  I see that _As of version 1.2, AngularJS ships with SCE enabled by default._ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce  Thus, this is likely why `null` and `sce` work the same.  Yes?

Answer (score 0):

As said in [gitHub issue](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1101#issuecomment-291128047)

Using sce solved the issue

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy("sce");
```